# Actualizar consulta de datos de Excel en Python

Tags: python, excel

Tengo un libro excel que actualiza los datos con una consulta a SQL.
Ahora estoy intentando poder ejecutarlo desde python. La secuencia sería:

1. Abrir archivo excel
2. Ejecutar consulta (Actualizar Todo)-->este es el paso que no consigo desarrollar
   [image: Paso2]

3. Guardar fichero excel
4. Cerrar archivo excel

Dejo aquí el código en python:

**

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book(r'ruta\archivo.xlsm')
Macro1 = wb.macro("Módulo1.Macro")
Macro1()
wb.save('archivo.xlsm')
wb.close()
```

**

Comment: ¿Podría tener algo que ver el carácter especial de "M**ó**dulo1"? ¿Has probado a cambiar el nombre al módulo?

Comment: en verdad la macro se debe ejecutar tras la actualización de la consulta. Lo he probado y la macro no es el problema. Faltaría una línea en el script que actualizara la consulta

Comment: Es que por un lado hablas del botón de Excel "Actualizar todo" y por otro lado de una Consulta a SQL. Bueno... si es lo del botón, por qué no añades esa acción a la macro, o a una nueva si no las puedes mezclar? En VBA sería `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`

Comment: Sí, puede ser una solución, pero no quiero incluirlo en la macro porque es un libro que utilizan otras personas. La idea es poder actualizar los datos directamente desde python sin modificar la macro. He probado a activar la actualización de vínculos automáticamente cuando abro el fichero, pero cuando abro el fichero desde python no funciona y sí cuando lo abro manualmente

Comment: De acuerdo... entonces, si no puedes editar la Macro ni hacer una nueva... poco puedo ayudar, porque en la documentación de xlwings no hay método para actualizar todo. Suerte!

Comment: Gracias por la propuesta. Al fin he encontrado el método para actualizar sin tener que hacerlo a través de macro: wb.api.RefreshAll()